# Can you integrate a function of two variables with respect to one variable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Similar to how we take the partial derivative of a function $f(x,y)$ by holding one of the variables constant, why can we not take the integral of a function $f(x,y)$ by holding one variable constant?

For example why don't these equal $\int xy \, dx = \frac{x^2}{2}y$, assuming $y$ is a variable?

Comment: What makes you think that we cannot do that?

Comment: Who told you that it is impossible?

Comment: @SangchulLee well if I have a function x*y = dy/dx, I need to do separation by variables rather than just directly integrating and treating y as a constant

Comment: It would become $\int x*y dx = \int dy/dx * dx$

Comment: That's not what the question asks though...

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis well if it's possible to do what i ask in my question, then my solution to x*y=y' would be incorrect

Comment: $dy$ and $dx$ are not numbers so you cannot treat them as such.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I know, so i'm not sure how that's relevant

Comment: Please edit your question to include details about your specific problem. What you are asking here in the comments is quite different from what is asked in the question.

Comment: You have to be clear as to whether the two variables $x$ and $y$ are independent or not. I implicitly assumed that you are asking about the case where they are independent (in which case you can simply integrate out one variable while holding the others), but in your comments you are considering the case where they are dependent.

Comment: You have two very different questions in your post. Can we take a partial integral? Yes. Does partial integration solve problems where the variables are not independent? Not without more work, no.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can dot it. Let us see an example if you meant (antiderivatives and not the defined integral):

When you write $\int f(x)dx$, if it can be expressed by an expression, you have the answer $\int f(x) dx=F(x) +C$, where $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$ and $ C \in \mathbb{R}$ is any constant (does not depend on $x$). Now, if $f$ depends on $x$ and $y$, like $f(x,y)$, when you write $\int f(x,y)dx$ you are integrating in $x$ and considering $y$ as a constante. So, the answer still holds like $\int f(x,y) dx=F(x,y)+C$, but now $C$ is a function that depends on $y$. For instance:

Let $f(x,y)= 2x + y^2$. Then, $F(x,y) = x^2 + xy^2 + g(y) +C$ has the property: $$\frac{d}{dx}F(x,y)= 2x$$
since $g(y)$ is constant in $x$. So, we write $$\int f(x,y) dx=F(x,y)+ G(y)$$
where $G(y)=g(y)+C$.